# R Error GoogleNewsSource inherits(x, "Source") is not TRUE

Tags: r, tm

I am using tm and tm.plugin.webmining package to try to read in some Goggle news and do some basic analysis on them. However, I am facing a problem at the very beginning:

```
googleNewsCorpus <- Corpus (GoogleNewsSource("Google"))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: inherits(x, "Source") is not TRUE
```

Please help. I am using R version 3.1, R Studio Version 0.98.1091, tm version 0.6, and tm.plugin.webmining version 1.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I cast the result into a WebCorpus:

```
gnewsCorpus <- WebCorpus(GoogleNewsSource("Google"))
```

I can now use this for subsequent 'tm' analysis:

```
data <- tm_map(gnewsCorpus,removeWords, stopwords("english"))
...
```

**A related question though:** After I have done all analysis, created a term-document matrix, clustered using hclust(), how do I put the news headings in the cluster dendogram?

```
...
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(data)
h <- hclust(dist(t(tdm),method="cosine"))
plot(h)
```

Answer (score 0):

The related query is also answered thus:

```
newsheadings <- character(length(gnewsCorpus))
for (i in 1:length(gnewsCorpus)){
  newsheadings[i] <- gnewsCorpus[[i]]$meta$heading
}
...
plot(h, labels = newsheadings)
```